# Force props on functional component child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a tooltip component with `React.cloneElement`. It works fine until I use it with a functional component. Then the events I want to add are ignored (because they are not in the props of the child?). Can I force them onto the outermost/first child of my functional child component?

```
class Tooltip extends Component {
    render() {
        return React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
            return React.cloneElement(child, {
                onMouseEnter: () => { console.log('onMouseEnter'); }
            })
        });
    }
}

<Tooltip right text="Logout">
  <button>
     This works fine.
  </button>
</Tooltip>

<Tooltip right text="Logout">
  <MyButton>
     This does not work (resp. it works only if the child passes the {...props} manually)  
  </MyButton>
</Tooltip>
```

Comment: This wouldn't work without cloning either. `<MyButton>` would have to support that prop.

Comment: OK. But there must be a way how other tooltip libraries do this, right?

Comment: @Obiwahn You can use React.context for that. It will help you with sharing some common state across the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work because `React.cloneElement` only sees the "top-level" element and not the contents of it.

Assuming `<MyButton />` looks like:

```js
const MyButton = ({ children }) => <button>{children}</button>;
```

Then, when you do:

```js
<Tooltip>
  <MyButton>
    This does not work (resp. it works only if the child passes the
    manually)
  </MyButton>
</Tooltip>
```

`React.cloneElement` attaches the `onMouseEnter` prop to the `MyButton` functional component instead of the `<button>` element inside the `MyButton` and since `MyButton` is not a valid element the event does not work on it.

You can log the values for `children` in `Tooltip` class and verify the same.

```json
{
  type: "button"
  key: ".0"
  ref: null
  props: Object
  children: "This works fine."
  onClick: ƒ onClick() {}
  _owner: FiberNode
  _store: Object
}
```

This is the representation when using:

```
<Tooltip right text="Logout">
  <button>
     This works fine.
  </button>
</Tooltip>`:
```

vs

```json
{
  type: ƒ MyButton() {}
  key: ".0"
  ref: null
  props: Object
  children: "Thss does not work (resp. it works only if the child passes the 
             manually)"
  onClick: ƒ onClick() {}
  _owner: FiberNode
  _store: Object
}
```

for

```
<Tooltip>
  <MyButton>
    This does not work (resp. it works only if the child passes the
    manually)
  </MyButton>
</Tooltip>:
```

Ideally, what you are trying to do should be done using [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), but for an easier workaround, you can pass through the props you receive on `MyButton` to its children.

Comment: Thank you for this elaborated answer. Could you give a direction on how this would be solved with Context? (Assuming that I have no access to and cannot change MyButton)

Comment: Context would not work if you don't have access to `MyButton`. If this is a third party component you are using then you should check their docs for the `MyButton` component and if they allow passing through the props to the children of `MyButton` that you pass to `MyButton`.

If my answer was helpful, please mark it as "accepted".